# Shorten code to filter data

Tags: r, filtering

Take this code:

```
quite_long_data_frame_name <- data.frame(variable.name = rnorm(50, 3, 2))

quite_long_data_frame_name$variable.name[quite_long_data_frame_name$variable.name > 2 & quite_long_data_frame_name$variable.name < 3] <- NA
```

In the last line, `quite_long_data_frame_name$variable.name` needs to be repeated 3 times. Is there any way to achieve same result but using `quite_long_data_frame_name$variable.name` just once? Can `dplyr` or `magrittr` achieve this?

Comment: @richardscriven I think you misunderstood

Comment: Note that "filter" means to subset (as in cut down) data, at least in the context of dplyr.  What you really want to do is conditional modify some values.

Answer (score 1):

Use `subset` and the negation of that logical vector:

```
subset( quite_long_data_frame_name, !(variable.name > 2 & variable.name < 3) )
```

If you want to destructively modfiy the original, then just assign that value to the original.

If your really do want a result with the NA's:

```
within( quite_long_data_frame_name, is.na(variable.name) <- 
                                     (variable.name > 2 & variable.name < 3) )
```

You will need to assign back to  quite_long_data_frame_name if you want this result to replace the original.

Comment: Note that this filters in the `dplyr` sense, rather than setting to `NA` as the question suggests.

Comment: True. I'll propose a `within` solution.

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, I suppose you would do

```
quite_long_data_frame_name %>%
mutate(variable.name=ifelse(variable.name>2 & variable.name<3, NA, variable.name))
```

Now you only type the dataframe name once, but you have to type the variable name 4 times instead of 3.  Could help if the variable names are short compared to the dataframe name. Unfortunately no more terse `dplyr` solution comes to mind.

As an alternative to the `attach` solution, use `with`

```
with(quite_long_data_frame_name, variable.name[variable.name > 2 & variable.name < 3] <- NA)
```

Still pretty long.  I don't know of any way to do this without typing `variable.name` at least 3 times.

Give your variables shorter names?  :)

Note that if you wanted to actually filter (in the `dplyr` sense) it's easier

```
quite_long_data_frame_name %>%
filter(variablename > 2 & variablename < 3)
```

but this is shorter in base R as well.

===== Edit ==========

This this specific conditional, you can use the `%between%` operator in the `data.table` package.  Shorter, but not very general.  Aggregating everything here, we get

```
with(quite_long_data_frame_name, is.na(variable.name) <- variable.name %between% c(2, 3))
```

Comment: Can `mutate` handle `is.na<-`?

Comment: AFAIK `mutate` requires `variable.name=` but I am very new to `dplyr` and could be wrong.

Comment: This won't work?: `mutate( is.na(variable.name) <- (variable.name > 2 & variable.name < 3))` ?

Comment: Not as written but that doesn't mean there isn't a way.